# add to multidimensional array child

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have this code that will list of categories and subcategories but I need it to be inside childCategories, I already managed to get add in 2nd level, if there is more than 2nd level, I will not able to add it. The scenario will be like this:-

The Parent category is "Electronic" and the subcategories is "Smart Phone" and "Laptops", inside Smart Phone, there is Asus and Samsung and Same goes to Laptops. In Laptops category there is "Alienware Series" and "Vostro Series".

Electronics

-> Smartphone

--> Asus

--> Samsung

-> Laptops

--> HP

--> Dell ---> Alienware Series, Vostro Series

I want the array to be like this...

```
Array
        (
            [categoryId] => 3
            [title] => Electronic
            [bannerImage] => elect.jpg
            [childCategories] => Array
                (
                    Array
                        (
                            [categoryId] => 4
                            [title] => Smartphone
                            [bannerImage] => smartphone-banner.png
                            [childCategories] => Array
                                (
                                    Array
                                        (
                                        [categoryId] => 4
                                        [title] => Asus
                                        [bannerImage] => 
                                        [childCategories] => Array
                                                            (

                                                            )
                                    ),

                                    Array
                                        (
                                        [categoryId] => 5
                                        [title] => Samsung
                                        [bannerImage] => 
                                        [childCategories] => Array
                                                            (

                                                            )
                                    )


                                ),
                            Array
                            (
                                    [categoryId] => 6
                                    [title] => Laptops
                                    [bannerImage] => 
                                    [childCategories] => Array
                                    (
                                        Array
                                        (
                                        [categoryId] => 7
                                        [title] => HP
                                        [bannerImage] => 
                                        [childCategories] => Array
                                                            (

                                                            )
                                        ),

                                        Array
                                        (
                                            [categoryId] => 8
                                            [title] => Dell
                                            [bannerImage] => 
                                            [childCategories] => Array
                                                                (

                                                                    Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [categoryId] => 9
                                                                        [title] => Alienware Series
                                                                        [bannerImage] => 
                                                                        [childCategories] => Array
                                                                        (

                                                                        )
                                                                    ),
                                                                    Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [categoryId] => 10
                                                                        [title] => Vostro Series
                                                                        [bannerImage] => 
                                                                        [childCategories] => Array
                                                                        (

                                                                        )
                                                                    )


                                                            ),

                                        )

                                    )
                            )
                        )
                )
```

Here is my code:-

```
if($category->getData('level') > 2) {
    $temp_array = array();

    $paths = explode("/", $category->getData('path'));
    for ($x=0; $x <= count($paths); $x++) {

        if($x == 0 || $x == 1) {
            unset($paths[$x]);
        }
        else {
            $temp_array['categoryId'] = $category->getData('entity_id');
            $temp_array['title'] = $category->getData('name');
            $temp_array['bannerImage'] = $category->getData('image');
            $temp_array['childCategories'] = array();
            $temp_array['path'] = $category->getData('path');
            $temp_array['parent'] = $category->getData('parent_id');
            $temp_array['level'] = $category->getData('level');
            $category_array[$category->getData('parent_id')]['childCategories'][$category->getData('entity_id')] = $temp_array;                     
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, if future there is will be more subcategories to be added in. So therefore it cannot be normal array assignment.

**Update 3**

```
{
    "3": {
        "categoryId": "3",
        "title": "Electronic",
        "bannerImage": "elect.jpg",
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "2",
        "path": "1/2/3"
    },
    "4": {
        "categoryId": "4",
        "title": "Smartphone",
        "bannerImage": "smartphone-banner.png",
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "3",
        "path": "1/2/3/4"
    },
    "5": {
        "categoryId": "5",
        "title": "Laptop",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "3",
        "path": "1/2/3/5"
    },
    "6": {
        "categoryId": "6",
        "title": "Health",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "2",
        "path": "1/2/6"
    },
    "7": {
        "categoryId": "7",
        "title": "Vitamin",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "6",
        "path": "1/2/6/7"
    },
    "9": {
        "categoryId": "9",
        "title": "Fashion",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "2",
        "path": "1/2/9"
    },
    "10": {
        "categoryId": "10",
        "title": "For Her",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "9",
        "path": "1/2/9/10"
    },
    "11": {
        "categoryId": "11",
        "title": "For Him",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "9",
        "path": "1/2/9/11"
    },
    "12": {
        "categoryId": "12",
        "title": "Samsung",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "4",
        "path": "1/2/3/4/12"
    },
    "13": {
        "categoryId": "13",
        "title": "Dell",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "5",
        "path": "1/2/3/5/13"
    },
    "14": {
        "categoryId": "14",
        "title": "Alienware",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "13",
        "path": "1/2/3/5/13/14"
    },
    "15": {
        "categoryId": "15",
        "title": "Vostro",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "13",
        "path": "1/2/3/5/13/15"
    },
    "timestamp": "2017-10-31 04:20:20"
}
```

Comment: @mickmackusa the arrow is just visual view of how the category looks like.

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  However, if I am going to attempt to help you, I must also spend the time to write a minimal/complete set of sample input so that I can develop and test my solution.  -- This makes answering your question unappealing (to most volunteers).

Comment: @mickmackusa Noted, will generate a json format for you.

Comment: @mickmackusa Json has been generated

Comment: Your json data is already appropriately nested, please offer the unnested input, not the expected output.  There is nothing for me to do with that sample json data.

Comment: @mickmackusa you mean listing all the categories without any nested?

Comment: Isn't that how mysql (or whatever your source) spits it out for you?  To solve this recursion question, I will be taking flat array data and repackaging it using parent-child relationships to form a new multi-dimensional array.  If you can offer the flat data, my job is to write the code that restructures it.  Your question seems to ask how to nest an undetermined number of children -- this requires recursion.

Comment: @mickmackusa Updated, please check Update 2

Comment: Please understand, there is no relationship data in your Update2.  Nothing in the subarrays will tell php how to associate parents to children.  There must be something more in the input data that will indicate how to recurse.  I expect `childCategories` should be changed to `childIds` which would hold the `key`(s) of its children, so that I can swap those integers for whole subarrays.

Comment: @mickmackusa Updated with more data, childCategories data are added it manually, I need to check by `path` in order to childCategories

Comment: @mickmackusa Please check update 3

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question... Where is parent `2`?  I can ignore the missing `1` and `8` because they don't have any listed kids, but the missing `2` will create "orphans".  Do I need to generate an empty `2` in my code? or do you have a `2` subarray to throw into the data (easier for me if you do.)?

Comment: @mickmackusa due to the system limitation, the parent 2 is actually the root category, which will not be shown to user. You can generate empty 2.

Answer (score 0):

Using your json input data:

```
$json='{
    "3": {
        "categoryId": "3",
        "title": "Electronic",
        "bannerImage": "elect.jpg",
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "2",
        "path": "1/2/3"
    },
    "4": {
        "categoryId": "4",
        "title": "Smartphone",
        "bannerImage": "smartphone-banner.png",
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "3",
        "path": "1/2/3/4"
    },
    "5": {
        "categoryId": "5",
        "title": "Laptop",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "3",
        "path": "1/2/3/5"
    },
    "6": {
        "categoryId": "6",
        "title": "Health",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "2",
        "path": "1/2/6"
    },
    "7": {
        "categoryId": "7",
        "title": "Vitamin",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "6",
        "path": "1/2/6/7"
    },
    "9": {
        "categoryId": "9",
        "title": "Fashion",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "2",
        "path": "1/2/9"
    },
    "10": {
        "categoryId": "10",
        "title": "For Her",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "9",
        "path": "1/2/9/10"
    },
    "11": {
        "categoryId": "11",
        "title": "For Him",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "9",
        "path": "1/2/9/11"
    },
    "12": {
        "categoryId": "12",
        "title": "Samsung",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "4",
        "path": "1/2/3/4/12"
    },
    "13": {
        "categoryId": "13",
        "title": "Dell",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "5",
        "path": "1/2/3/5/13"
    },
    "14": {
        "categoryId": "14",
        "title": "Alienware",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "13",
        "path": "1/2/3/5/13/14"
    },
    "15": {
        "categoryId": "15",
        "title": "Vostro",
        "bannerImage": null,
        "childCategories": [],
        "parent": "13",
        "path": "1/2/3/5/13/15"
    },
    "timestamp": "2017-10-31 04:20:20"
}';
```

I am using a non-recursive approach.  It is more of a stacking technique to nest children into their parents whereby I foster the deepest children first and work up from the "bottom".  See my inline comments for step-by-step explanation.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YtNVU))

```
$array=json_decode($json,true);
unset($array['timestamp']);  // remove unwanted timestamp
uasort($array,function($a,$b){return substr_count($b['path'],'/')<=>substr_count($a['path'],'/');});  // sort by depth (deepest to shallowest)
foreach($array as $key=>&$subarray){
    $data=array_intersect_key($subarray,['title'=>'','bannerImage'=>'','childCategories'=>'']);  // store only vital data based on nominated keys
    if(isset($array[$subarray['parent']])){
        $array[$subarray['parent']]['childCategories'][$key]=$data;  // insert into parent (on same level)
        unset($array[$key]);  // remove child from original "unnested" location
    }else{
        $subarray=$data;  // no movement needed, just trim unwanted elements from subarray
    }
}
ksort($array);  // resort by first level keys, ASC
var_export($array);
```

This is the output:

```
array (
  3 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Electronic',
    'bannerImage' => 'elect.jpg',
    'childCategories' => 
    array (
      4 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Smartphone',
        'bannerImage' => 'smartphone-banner.png',
        'childCategories' => 
        array (
          12 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'Samsung',
            'bannerImage' => NULL,
            'childCategories' => 
            array (
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      5 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Laptop',
        'bannerImage' => NULL,
        'childCategories' => 
        array (
          13 => 
          array (
            'title' => 'Dell',
            'bannerImage' => NULL,
            'childCategories' => 
            array (
              14 => 
              array (
                'title' => 'Alienware',
                'bannerImage' => NULL,
                'childCategories' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
              15 => 
              array (
                'title' => 'Vostro',
                'bannerImage' => NULL,
                'childCategories' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Health',
    'bannerImage' => NULL,
    'childCategories' => 
    array (
      7 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Vitamin',
        'bannerImage' => NULL,
        'childCategories' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Fashion',
    'bannerImage' => NULL,
    'childCategories' => 
    array (
      10 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'For Her',
        'bannerImage' => NULL,
        'childCategories' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      11 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'For Him',
        'bannerImage' => NULL,
        'childCategories' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```